# Pandas KeyError: 'not in index' when plotting a time Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

the following code used to work with pandas-0.22.0, seaborn-0.8.1, and matplotlib-2.2.2.

it now fails with pandas-0.23.3, seaborn-0.9.0, and matplotlib-2.2.2

```
dv = df.loc[(df['Ms'] >= 0)] 
msec_to_min = 60 * 1000
ax = dv[['Watts', 'Speed', 'RPMs', 'Hr', 'Load']]
ax.plot.line(figsize=(20, 10), x=dv['Ms']/msec_to_min)
```

throws a KeyError: `[0.00000000e+00 1.66666667e-02 3.33333333e-02 ... 7.82000000e+01\n 7.82166667e+01 7.82333333e+01] not in index`

whenever the time Series is applied to the x= parameter

I have no idea how to resolve the KeyError exception

code stub to reproduce the reported problem:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Ms': [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
    'Watts': [0, 0, 0, 0, 31],
    'Speed': [0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 3.335272],
    'RPMs': [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
    'Hr': [0, 0, 0, 0, 91],
    'Miles': [0.000000, 0.000231, 0.000463, 0.000694, 0.000926],
    'Load': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})

dv = df.loc[(df['Ms'] >= 0)]
ax = dv[['Watts', 'Speed', 'RPMs', 'Hr', 'Load']]
ax.plot.line(figsize=(20, 10), x=dv['Ms']/60000)
```

Comment: Do you mean to have `ax` as axis or a dataframe? Does `dv` have a column `Ms`? Can you post a [MCVE] ?

Comment: code stub attached as an answer

Comment: Edit it back to your question please. That is not an answer.